# gnuplot draw adjcent 3D cubic with different color

Tags: gnuplot

I am studing container loading algorithm. When I have loading plan, I use gnuplot to plot the plan (3D) as in attachment. As all goods are cubic, I want to plot one cubic border line by yellow, next brown, then yellow, next brown. Of course, the color could be any. My purpose is that I could see better the cubic loading plan. Currently, I could only plot with same color.[image: loading plan]

The better is that Container cubic border line is its own.

Part of my test data is at /2/

/2/

```
++++++container 40 feet data###########
0          0         0
12.0       0         0
12.0       2.3       0
0          2.3       0
0          0         0
0          0         0
0          0         2.5
12.0       0         2.5
12.0       2.3       2.5
0          2.3       2.5   
### container 40 feet data#########      

##########first cubic ############# 
0     0       2.5
0.0   0.0     0.0
0.64  0.0     0.0
0.64  0.66    0.0
0.0   0.66    0.0
0.0   0.0     0.0
0.0   0.0     1.93
0.64  0.0     1.93
0.64  0.66    1.93
0.0   0.66    1.93
0.0   0.0     1.93

0.64  0.0    0.0
0.64  0.0    1.93

0.64  0.66   0.0
0.64  0.66   1.93

0.0   0.66   0.0
0.0   0.66   1.93

################# Second cubic#################
0.64   0.0   0.0
1.27   0.0   0.0
1.27   0.66   0.0
0.64   0.66   0.0
0.64   0.0   0.0
0.64   0.0   1.93
1.27   0.0   1.93
1.27   0.66   1.93
0.64   0.66   1.93
0.64   0.0   1.93

1.27   0.0   0.0
1.27   0.0   1.93

1.27   0.66   0.0
1.27   0.66   1.93

0.64   0.66   0.0
0.64   0.66   1.93
```

Comment: please post the gnuplot commands you used

Comment: splot 'cubeTest.dat' with lines